# Parameter pack inconsistent deduction

Tags: c++11, templates

```
void f(int&, int&);
void f(double&, double&, double&);
// some other helper functions with params always lvalue refs

template <typename... Types>
void fun(void(*g)(Types...), Types&&... args) {
 g(args...);
}

int main() {
int x = 1;
int y = 2;
fun(f,x,y);
fun(f, 1, 2);
}
```

I want to have a function template that calls another helper function with its parameter pack. In the caller function the parameters can be lvalue/rvalue refs but the in the helper function they will always be lvalue refs since they are being passed by the calling function. I don't know how should the first parameter (the type of the helper function pointer) in the caller function should be declared to avoid having this inconsistent type deduction problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that worked for me!

```
template <typename... Types>
void fun(void(*g)(typename std::remove_reference<Types>::type&...), Types&&... args) {
 g(args...);
}
```

Comment: First, if you can answer a question yourself within 12 minutes after asking it, then maybe you did not do enough research before asking. :-) Now, some suggestions for improving your code: You can replace `remove_reference` with `decay`, which in particular removes cv qualifiers, something you really want in this case. Also, using `g(std::forward<Types>( args ) ...)` instead of `args...` will make sure that your parameters are forwarded as efficiently as possible (»perfect forwarding«).

Comment: @MarkusMayr Dunno about decay -- removing `const` makes the body not compile.